# Animating a div with CSS animations with a slight delay between two

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

What I am trying to do is basically a notification bar which I want to show and hide with CSS animation. The problem is I am not being able to make a good amount of delay between the occurring of two animations.

**HTML**

```
<div id="notification" class="alert" role="alert"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#notification').html('This place is already occupied!').addClass('alert-warning animated bounceInDown').show().delay(5000).addClass('bounceOutUp');
```

**CSS**

```
#notification {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1200 !important;
}
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
    from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    }
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    }
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
    }
}
@keyframes bounceInDown {
    from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    }
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    }
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
    }
}
.bounceInDown {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
    animation-name: bounceInDown;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounceOutUp {
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    }
    40%, 45% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
    }
}
@keyframes bounceOutUp {
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    }
    40%, 45% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
    }
}
.bounceOutUp {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceOutUp;
    animation-name: bounceOutUp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `animationend` event listener with a `setTimeout()` that adds the next animation after the animation has run.

```js
var $notification = $('#notification'),
    delay = 5000;
$notification.html('This place is already occupied!').addClass('alert-warning animated bounceInDown').show().one('animationend',function() {  
  var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $notification.addClass('bounceOutUp');
  },delay)
});
```

```css
#notification {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1200 !important;
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
  from,
  60%,
  75%,
  90%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInDown {
  from,
  60%,
  75%,
  90%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.bounceInDown {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
  animation-name: bounceInDown;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceOutUp {
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }
  40%,
  45% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceOutUp {
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }
  40%,
  45% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
  }
}

.bounceOutUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceOutUp;
  animation-name: bounceOutUp;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notification" class="alert" role="alert"></div>
```

You could also use the same technique and just alter the `animation-delay` of the `.bounceOutUp` class to be 5s instead of using a timer.

```js
var $notification = $('#notification');

$notification.html('This place is already occupied!').addClass('alert-warning animated bounceInDown').show().one('animationend',function() {
  $(this).addClass('bounceOutUp');
});
```

```css
#notification {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1200 !important;
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
  from,
  60%,
  75%,
  90%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInDown {
  from,
  60%,
  75%,
  90%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.bounceInDown {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
  animation-name: bounceInDown;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceOutUp {
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }
  40%,
  45% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceOutUp {
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }
  40%,
  45% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
  }
}

.bounceOutUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceOutUp;
  animation-name: bounceOutUp;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notification" class="alert" role="alert"></div>
```

Comment: Is it `on` or `one`?

Comment: @Ayan use whichever you prefer. I assumed you just wanted this to run once. http://api.jquery.com/one/ http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Yes definitely once, just that I didnt know about `one` =)

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if i understand you correctly, but you can make delay with css:

```
div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

Comment: Its causing my first animation to not occur.